# Racket - Using Two Lists and Outputing String

Tags: string, list, racket

For reference I am programming `Racket` in `DrRacket`.

The "language" I am using is `Intermediate Student with lambda`.

**That said, I should note that these are not using high-order functions or lambda**.

I am writing a function called `winner-by-all` that consumes a list of candidates and a list of votes, and returns the name of the winner (one with the highest number of votes).

I can get it to output the largest number, but not name of the winner itself (string).

Here is my `winner-by-all` function, which is not correct:

```
;; Signature: winner-by-all: list-of-candidates list-of-votes -> string
;; Purpose: Consumes a list of candidates and a list of votes, and returns 
;;          the name of the winner by the winner-takes-all strategy.
;; Tests:
(check-expect (winner-by-all empty empty) empty)
(check-expect (winner-by-all listofCandidates listofVotes) "Blake")
;; Define:
(define (winner-by-all aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (voting-tally-candidate (max (voting-tally-numVotes (first (tally-by-all listofCandidates listofVotes)))))]
    )
  )
```

When run, I get an error saying:

```
voting-tally-candidate: expects a voting-tally, given 3
```

So my function makes more sense, here are a few other parts of my code to fill in the gaps:

`tally-by`:

```
;; Signature: tally-by: (helper function) list-of-candidates list-of-votes -> list-of-Voting-Tallies
;; Purpose: Consumes a helper function, a list of candidate names, and a list of
;;          votes and produces a list of voting-tallies.
;; Define:
(define (tally-by helper aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (cons (make-voting-tally (first aloc) 
                                   (helper (first aloc) alov))
                (tally-by helper (rest aloc) alov))]
    )
  )
```

`tally-by-all`:

```
;; Signature: tally-by-all: list-of-candidates list-of-votes -> list-of-Voting-Tallies
;; Purpose: Consumes a list of candidate names and a list of votes and produces a
;;          list of voting-tallies.
;;          (Winner-Takes-All strategy).
;; Tests:
(check-expect (tally-by-all empty empty) empty)
(check-expect (tally-by-all listofCandidates listofVotes) (cons (make-voting-tally "Blake" 3)
                                                          (cons (make-voting-tally "Ash" 0)
                                                          (cons (make-voting-tally "Bob" 0)
                                                          (cons (make-voting-tally "Will" 0)
                                                          (cons (make-voting-tally "Joey" 0) empty))))))
;; Define:
(define (tally-by-all aloc alov)
  (tally-by top-votes-for aloc alov))
```

`listofVotes`:

```
;; Data Definition
(define-struct vote (choice1 choice2 choice3))
;; A vote is a structure: (make-vote String String String). 
;; interp. 3 candidates that one person has voted for (String).

(define vote1
  (make-vote "Blake" "Joey" "Will"))

(define vote2
  (make-vote "Blake" "Bob" "Ash"))

(define vote3
  (make-vote "Blake" "Ash" "Blake"))

(define listofVotes
  (list vote1 vote2 vote3))
```

`top-votes-for`:

```
;; Signature: top-votes-for: string list-of-strings -> number
;; Purpose: Consumes a name and a list of votes and produces the number of
;;          times that the given name was the first choice vote in the list of votes.
;;          (This tallies points under winner-takes-all strategy.)
;; Tests:
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Blake" empty) 0)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Blake" listofVotes) 3)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Bob" listofVotes) 0)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Ash" listofVotes) 0)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Joey" listofVotes) 0)
(check-expect (top-votes-for "Will" listofVotes) 0)
;; Define:
(define (top-votes-for cand alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? alov) 0]
    [(string=? (vote-choice1 (first alov)) cand) (+ 1 (top-votes-for cand (rest alov)))]
    [else (top-votes-for cand (rest alov))]
    )
  )
```

`listofCandidates`:

```
(define listofCandidates
  (list "Blake" "Ash" "Bob" "Will" "Joey"))
```

`voting-tally` structure:

```
;; Data Definition
(define-struct voting-tally (candidate numVotes))
;; A voting-tally is a structure: (make-voting-tally String Number). 
;; interp. a candidate (String) and how many votes said
;;         candidate has gotten (Number).
```

I am hoping someone is able to assist me with `winner-by-all` function definitions as I am unsure how to make it work the way it is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Intermediate student with lambda** you can use high-order functions such as `argmax`:

```
(define (winner-by-all aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (voting-tally-candidate (argmax voting-tally-numVotes
                                          (tally-by-all listofCandidates listofVotes)))]
    )
  )
```

---

If you really need to implement it without high-order functions and lambda expressions, you can simulate `argmax` with your own function that recursively iterate over all results of `tally-by-all` and select the voting-tally with the highest number of votes.

```
(define (best-candidate left-candidates best)
  (if (null? left-candidates)
      best
      (let ([fst (car left-candidates)])
        (if (or (null? best)
                (> (voting-tally-numVotes fst) (voting-tally-numVotes best)))
            (best-candidate (cdr left-candidates) fst)
            (best-candidate (cdr left-candidates) best)))))
```

Then use `best-candidate` to do the job instead of `argmax`:

```
(define (winner-by-all aloc alov)
  (cond
    [(empty? aloc) empty]
    [else (voting-tally-candidate (best-candidate (tally-by-all listofCandidates listofVotes) null))]
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, however. In `best-candidate`, what do `left-candidates` and `best` equate to? Like what would I have to type into the window below the definitions window (forgot the name) to test out the function `best-candidate`?

Comment: `(best-candidate (tally-by-all listofCandidates listofVotes) null)`. The first argument (`left-candidates`) is a list of `voting-tally` structures and the second (`best`) is an accumulator representing the best `voting-tally` found so far (`null` for the first call).